# Python Socket connect from another network

Tags: python, sockets

I had done port forwarding which ask me for Internal IP, Internal Port, External Port and Protocol.
For internal ip i write device's ip which server.py runs in, for internal and external ports 23456, and for protocol i choose TCP

**Server.py**

```
import socket

port = 23456

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('', port))

    s.listen(1)
except socket.error as msg:
    print(msg)

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    txt = 'Connected'
    print(addr)
    c.send(txt.encode('utf-8'))
    c.close
```

**Client.py**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 23456

try:
    s.connect(('public ip address',port))

    re = s.recv(1024)
    print(re.decode('utf-8'))

    s.close()
except socket.error as msg:
    print(msg)
```

When i start Server.py and Client.py later, nothing happens. Looks like it doesn't connect to the server.I run both files on same device (i think it isn't problem) (and i can't try it on devices which at different networks for now)

Comment: Code works fine with `localhost`, so it is a firewall/router issue.  You do need to add `()` to `c.close` in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to address `0.0.0.0`

How to:

```py
s.bind(('', port))
```

into

```py
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
```

And a reminder to change `c.close` into `c.close()` on Server.py